# HTTParty get request using Basic Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

I am trying to make get request to this address https://unicom24.ru/api/partners/requests/v1/locality/

I am using httparty gem. I need to use basic http Auth. 
I got my auth key and do request like this:

```
headers = {'Authorization' => 'Basic bMyAuthKeydv4K'}
HTTParty.get(
  "https://unicom24.ru/api/partners/requests/v1/locality/", 
  :headers => headers
)
```

And I get a reply:

```
@response=#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

unallowable  email or password.
What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTTParty` basic auth

```
auth = {username: 'user', password: 'pass'}

result = HTTParty.get(
  "https://unicom24.ru/api/partners/requests/v1/locality/", 
  basic_auth: auth
)
```

Comment: Why create a variable if you are only using it in one place?

Comment: I don't really think it makes it more readable. It makes it so you have to look around to find all args in the method call.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Your solution is using a username and password while the question is using a key.

Comment: HTTParty.get("https://unicom24.ru/api/partners/requests/v1/locality/", :headers => { 'Authorization' => "Basic bMyAuthKeydv4K" })